# Git push to a remote not updating files

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

I have a git repo set up with two remotes ORIGIN and WEB both are bare.

When pushing to ORIGIN the push completes the log shows the commit and the files are updated.

When pushing to WEB the push completes (a subsequent push says Everything up to date). The log on the web remote shows the commit occurred successfully but none of the files are modified according to the commit.

What could be going wrong please?

EDIT 1 - commands and replies as requested

```
local$  git branch
* master

remote$ git branch
* master


local$ git add newfile
local$ git commit -m "added newfile"

[master 591680a] added newfile
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 public_html/newfile


local$ git push web master

Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 324 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://user@myhost/home/user
c5b7713..591680a  master -> master


remote$ git log

commit 591680a73fdf535c44031cca545b2a47e8421fac
Author: Matthew Slight <matthew@slight.me>
Date:   Mon Oct 17 06:24:10 2016 +0400

added newfile


remote$ ls newfile

No such file or directory
```

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: how are you executing the `push` command?

Comment: Considering both remote repositories are _bare_, what files are you expecting to be modified?

Comment: Can you include the commands you are using - so we can get a better idea of what is going on?

Comment: @CharlesBailey bare in the git sense, not as in no files -- http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/

Comment: That article seems fairly accurate, in particular "[...] they contain no working or checked out copy of your source files". So, to rephrase my question: if the repository is bare, which files are you expecting to be modified: just the Git repository database files or some "on disk" copy of the file which you committed, and if the latter, what mechanism are you expecting to update this copy?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesBailey I was expecting the modified and added commited files on master, "on disk" on the remote to be updated.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Ohh I see what you are saying now. Basically the repository is not the same as the on disk source files themselves. So basically a bare repo doesn't do what I think it does, i.e. work on a set of "on disk" files.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try specifying the branches involved, like

```
$ git push web HEAD:master
```

(being `master` the branch you are pushing to the remote)

Comment: In addition, check that when looking for the modified files on WEB, that you are on the right branch and the branch reference is up to date.

Comment: @ScottNewson can you provide the commands to check please - see above for what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pulled and are on the right branch on your remote:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git status
```

and when doing `git log`, try `git log --decorate` instead, which will show the branch references as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not recommended to use the remote git repo in that way.
first of all, on the remote pc(server), you should init a bare git repo, using

git init --bare

and then set the workplace for the repo in  any other diretory on you server etc. google the usage of git init --bare

However, if you did want to work in that way, I think this will help:

*https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/making_a_remote_repo_update_when_changes_are_pushed_to_it/*